# Parsing XML for export To CSV

Tags: xml, powershell

Having issues getting the data I want out of an IIS config file in XML format.   Essentially there are a bunch of restricted ip addresses I need to grab along with the 4 numbers in the webappname ie (Example/3780) name and export to csv.

XML EXAMPLE

```
 <location path="Example/3780_Proxy_Test_01418277">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity>
                <add ipAddress="10.10.199.20" allowed="true" />
                <add ipAddress="10.10.81.80" subnetMask="255.255.255.240" allowed="true" />
                <add ipAddress="10.10.199.16" subnetMask="255.255.255.240" allowed="true" />
                <add ipAddress="10.10.163.150" allowed="true" />
                <add ipAddress="10.10.163.151" allowed="true" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="Example/3200_Proxy">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity>
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Right now I am stuck on the basics, just trying to get anything to match

```
$path = "\path\to\whatever.xml"
$xpath = "/configuration/location/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity"
select-xml -path $path -xpath $xpath |select-object ipaddress
```

Comment: The xPath is case sensitive. `select-xml -path $path -xpath '//ipsecurity'` returns nothing, but `select-xml -path $path -xpath '//ipSecurity'` returns the expected 5 nodes.